# mongodb - sort results such that a subset are retrieved first

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Consider the following collection, let's call it `things`. It has a number of documents

```
{ _id: 'aaa', foo: 82374 },
{ _id: 'bbb', foo: 32476 },
{ _id: 'ccc', foo: 25733 },
{ _id: 'ddd', foo: 45253 },
{ _id: 'eee', foo: 15545 }
```

I need to find all the documents which match a subset of `_id`'s which i already know AND which satisfy some other condition.

Furthermore, I want those documents which match on the `_id`'s to appear first in the sort order and the rest to be ordered by some other field.

Unfortunately I cannot simply find the matching `_id`'s first because `things` contains squillions of documents and I need to `skip` and `limit` the results. This results in an ugly, messy and complicated application level join.

Ideally what i want is this:

```
var query = {
  $or: [
    { _id: { $in: ['bbb', 'ddd'] } },
    { foo: { $lt: 20000 } }
  ]
};

var sort = {
  // somehow make the _id take priority here
  foo: 1
};

db.things.find(query).sort(sort).limit(100).toArray(callback);
```

Does anyone know if I can use an operator to achieve this?

Comment: The only way to do this is using aggregation.

Comment: I'm looking into it now. I'm trying to `$project` an `include` field onto the documents using a `$setIsSubset` operator but not having much luck. The field path `$_id` doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is " weighting" and to do that you need to use the [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline. The first stage in the pipeline is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage where you filter to allow only matching documents to pass unmodified into the next pipeline stage.Then you need to use the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) and [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort) pipeline operator as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33037905/3100115)

```js
db.things.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { "_id": { 
                "$in": ['bbb', 'ddd'] } 
            }, 
            { "foo": { "$lt": 20000 } } ] 
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "foo": 1, 
        "weight": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$_id", "bbb" ] }, 
                10, 
                { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$_id", "ddd" ] }, 
                    8, 
                    0
                ]}
            ]
        }
    }}, 
    { "$sort": { "weight": -1 }}
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{ "_id" : "bbb", "foo" : 32476, "weight" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "ddd", "foo" : 45253, "weight" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "eee", "foo" : 15545, "weight" : 0 }
```

---

Because the `$in` operator is not allowed in `$cond` you can use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) to return one element array array then use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) operator to check if that `_id` appear in your second array. Of course since the "input" of `$map` must be an array you need to use a [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal) expression.

```js
db.things.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "$or": [
            { _id: {
                "$in": ['bbb', 'ddd'] } 
            },
            { foo: { $lt: 20000 } }
        ] 
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "foo": 1,
        "weight": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$setIsSubset": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": { "$literal": ["id"] }, 
                        "as": "id", 
                        "in": "$_id"
                    }}, 
                    [ "bbb","ddd" ]
                ]},
                4, 
                0
            ]
        }
    }}, 
    { "$sort": { "weight": -1 } }
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "bbb", "foo" : 32476, "weight" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "ddd", "foo" : 45253, "weight" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "eee", "foo" : 15545, "weight" : 0 }
```

Note that this is more efficient if you have many "_id" in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can partially achieve this if you use the aggregation framework with `$project`. In the code below records that are only matched on `_id` appear first, however, this does not apply if both filter conditions are met. Unfortunately you can't use the `$in` operator in the `$project` clause.

```js
var query = [{
  $match: {
    $or: [{
      _id: {
        $in: ['bbb', 'ddd']
      }
    }, {
      foo: {
        $lt: 20000
      }
    }]
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    "_id": 1,
    "foo": 1,
    "sort_flag": {
      "$or": [{
        "$gte": ["$foo", 20000]
      }]
    }
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    "sort_flag": -1
  }
}]



db.things.aggregate(query)
```